# The parameter has been used in a way that constrains it to always be DerrivedType

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

Hi I just started programming in F# and am stuck on a type issue.
I have this function:

```
    member private this.UpdateStats<'T when 'T :> StatisticsBase>(passed: bool, stats: 'T) =
        //more stuff..
        stats
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
this.UpdateStats<GroupStats>(true, GroupStats(Id = Guid.NewGuid()))
```

The compiler says:

[image]
    The parameter has been used in a way that constrains it to always be GroupStats.

GroupStats inherit from StatisticsBase. What do I have to do to make the function usable for all entities that inherit from StatisticsBase?

types:

```
[<AllowNullLiteral>] 
type StatisticsBase() =
    member val Id = String.Empty with get,set

[<AllowNullLiteral>] 
type GroupStats() =
    inherit Stats()
```

StatisticsBase actually inherits from a C# type and is used in a repository, but I can reproduce the error with the code above

Comment: You'll have to show more code than that. I get no warning with the minimal implementation that you described. I suspect that the code of `UpdateStats` is not as simple as you let on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much back and forth, we have been able to ascertain that your actual non-working code is like this (tip for the future: provide more information):

```
type SomeType() =
    member this.M2() =
        this.M<GroupStats>(true, GroupStats())

    member private this.M<'T when 'T :> Stats>(x: bool, t: 'T) =
        t
```

This code will indeed produce the described error. This is because F# type inference works top-to-bottom, left-to-right. But there is an exception: classes (and other mutually recusrive definition groups) get two passes of type inference - first signatures, then bodies.

When the compiler first comes across the body of `M2`, it determines that method `M` must return `GroupStats`. Later, when the compiler comes across the body of `M`, it sees that `M`'s return value is the same as parameter `t`, which means that `M` must return `'T`. But since the compiler already knows, from examining the body of `M2`, that `M` must return `GroupStats`, it follows that `'T` must be `GroupStats`.

This doesn't happen if `M` is defined before `M2`: in this case, type inference will first encounter the body of `M` and correctly determine its return type to be `'T`, which will then match up with the body of `M2`, and the will be no problem.

From the above, two solutions can be formulated: first, you could define `M` before `M2`. Second, you could just explicitly specify the return type of `M`:

```
    member private this.M<'T when 'T :> Stats>(x: bool, t: 'T): 'T =
        t
```

This way, its return type will become known after the first pass, and the problem disappears.

Comment: Thanks, I know what I did wrong. If I first declare my the UpdateStats function and then call the function instead of the other way around everything works fine. Can you or anyone explain why I got the type error when the sequence was wrong? I mark your answer if you update the answer with the sequence thing. Thanks again!